# Windows 8 seems to be remote controlled?

Tags: windows-8, google-chrome, mouse, netstat

Recently I have detected that my mouse pointer moves by itself sometimes and even clicks/open random programs/files. I have no idea if this is hardware related since I am using my laptop connected to an external screen and mouse. My laptop has a touchscreen + touchpad and the lid is closed when I have noticed this event.

Anyway, I would appreciate to get a comment on following stats after running "netstat -a". Any help/suggestion on how I determine if my computer is under control of somebody else is really appreciated! How can I figure out if I am "hacked"?

Some examples after running "netstat -a":

```
 [chrome.exe]      TCP    192.168.1.2:61320      68.232.35.139:https    ESTABLISHED
 [Explorer.EXE]    TCP    192.168.1.2:61194      2.21.240.109:http      CLOSE_WAIT
 [chrome.exe]      TCP    192.168.1.2:61213      lb-in-f94:https        ESTABLISHED
```

Edit: I have disabled remote control since I discovered that my mouse was being "controlled" by something/somebody. The controlling by something/somebody happend again after that I did this.

Edit2:
Result of netstat -ano | find "listen" /i | find "0.0.0.0" /i | clip:

```
  TCP    0.0.0.0:135            0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       1052
  TCP    0.0.0.0:445            0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       4
  TCP    0.0.0.0:554            0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       6476
  TCP    0.0.0.0:2869           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       4
  TCP    0.0.0.0:7112           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       3200
  TCP    0.0.0.0:10243          0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       4
  TCP    0.0.0.0:49152          0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       948
  TCP    0.0.0.0:49153          0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       1104
  TCP    0.0.0.0:49154          0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       1136
  TCP    0.0.0.0:49155          0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       512
  TCP    0.0.0.0:49156          0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       1004
  TCP    127.0.0.1:35600        0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       4692
  TCP    127.0.0.1:50000        0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       4692
```

Comment: When searching for remote control software, it is a good idea to search for network ports in `listening` state to any IP (`0.0.0.0`). Try `netstat -ano | find "listen" /i | find "0.0.0.0" /i` and post the results (by modifying your original post).

Comment: If you have another computer on the same LAN, you can try some simple nMap scanning to the affected computer. It will show what ports are open. Not definitive, but will give us some ideas.

Comment: What "remote control" have you disabled, and how? VNC? RAdmin? TeamViewer? Remote Desktop?

Comment: The "remote control" I turned off is called "Remote assitance" in "System Properties". Followed the reverse of this guide: http://blogs.technet.com/b/digital_musketeer/archive/2011/09/14/how-to-enable-remote-desktop-on-the-windows-8-ctp.aspx

Comment: Tried netstat -ano | find "listen" /i | find "0.0.0.0" /i and posted the result in my original post. Does this show anything? Would it show anything if the "something/somebody" is not connected at the moment that I run the command? Will try nMap later on today, thanks for all the inputs!

Comment: Well, your `netstat`doesn't show anything strange, I would say. Maybe some pro coming over here later will help us. Usually, every remote control program has an `listening` port always open, and should apper here. You can search for info about your listening ports here: http://www.iana.org/assignments/service-names-port-numbers/service-names-port-numbers.xhtml

Comment: That guide reports about the usually named "Remote Desktop Protocol", AKA as "RDP". In a first sight, I can not find any remote control running. Seek for a TeamViewer process by doing `tasklist | find "teamvi" /i`. If you have no results, that is good too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The lid/screen of your laptop is triggering your trackpad which is causing the phantom movements.

Try using a thin piece of cardboard to keep the screen slightly open (1-2mm) while the lid is closed to see if the movements disappear.

Dell xps laptop by any chance?  I've had a few that exhibited this same behavior.

Comment: It does not happen always when the lid is down. It has only happend 2-3 times so far, however last time it helped to open the lid (the "control" over the mouse stopped as soon as I opened the lid). I have a lenovo ideapad u330. Do you still think it could be the case though it happens at random times and not always?

Comment: Could still be the trackpad sensors... You could try disabling the trackpad temporarily

Comment: Ok I will, thanks! My idea is to turn off the router next time I observer this. If there is no internet connection it should be imposible for somebody to control my computer right? In that case I can make sure that it depends on my hardware.